# FB share button goes away on page load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following haml

```
.share-fb-pop-up
.fb-contain
  .fb-share-button{"data-href" => "https://fls.net/proficiency_test", "data-layout" => "button", "data-mobile-iframe" => "false", "data-size" => "small"}
    %a.fb-xfbml-parse-ignore{:href => "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Ffls.net%2Fproficiency_test&src=sdkpreparse", :target => "_blank"} Share
.pop-button-div
  %button
    Close
```

I load the javascript like this:

```
:javascript
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '<my-app-id>',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.8'
  });
};

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And I know it works because I see it generate the text "Share" and when I remove the class `.fb-xfbml-parse-ignore` from the `a` tag it correctly links and shares via facebook. Is it something to do with running on localhost or rails making a call to the SDK in the page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `facebook-jssdk` initializing script is called before the share button has loaded.

1. Give your button an `id`
2. Use JS to find out when the button has loaded and call this function: `FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById("<given-id>"))`

Comment: how do you figure out when the button has loaded?

Comment: and do I give the `.fb-share-button` the id or the `<a>` tag within it?

Comment: 1) many options, can use `document.ready()`

2) the `id` is for any element containing your button so that FB knows where to search for it